# Release Management - Component Name

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have a Powershell script in my Tool that need to receive the "Component Name" as input parameter. Is there a way to pass that the name from the active Component that uses this tool to my PS script at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There is no related [variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn834972(v=vs.120).aspx) in Release Management. Seems can't be achieved at runtime.

As far as I know, you can use REST API to get a list of all Components that are used in this release template. Details about how to achieve you can refer [this blog](https://blogs.infosupport.com/getting-your-release-management-powershell-scripts-right/).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no predefined variable.

I can think of something which is not dynamic! Since the component will be the one to invoke your tool you pass your component name as an argument to the tool's script. (As i said it has to hardcoded for each component, not very dynamic)

Go to deployment tab and select your tool. In the arguments field, add what your want! Something like below,

.\YouPSSCriptNameInTheTool.ps1  -ComponmentName "Name Of the Current Component"

and ofcourse you need to add this parameter in your powershell script.